# Confusion about the order of the elements in a list

Tags: python

Took a Python class a few months ago so im a little rusty

```
lst= ["A", "B", "C", 2, 9 ]
    #  0,   1,   2 , 3, 4

print(lst[0:4])
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 2]
```

Why does the last 9 not get included in this? Shouldn't the 0:4 index the list from zero to the last digit because the 4 on the bottom which shows the index number represents the 4th character in the list??

Comment: python index does not include last element.  [0:4] will include 4 values: 0th, 1st, 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: If it helps, think of a slice `list[:x]` as "list **up to** x"